# how to separate comma in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to this data field:

```
MaritalStatus=M;Youngest=[-0.999,0.999];
```

Split to:

```
field name = Maritalstatus , data is M 
Field name = Youngest , Data is [-0.999,0.999];
```

How to write the SQL?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Do you want a generic varchar variable to be splitted in rows of key/value pairs. Is it?

Comment: Yes. SQLServer 2008. I will retrieve that data MaritalStatus=M;Youngest=[-0.999,0.999]; from other table. this data field is not fixed. may be change dyanmaically. Example , I can get the Eldest=[0.99] only from that table. I would like to split row of key/value pairs according to data changing. please help me

Comment: Much better to record X and Y values from your Data in separate fields. You'll thank me later.

Comment: Please give me sample code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit of fun with `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` but it's doable with only 2 pieces of information to extract:

```
select SUBSTRING(@string, 
           CHARINDEX('=', @string) + 1, 
           CHARINDEX(';', @string) - CHARINDEX('=', @string) - 1) as Maritalstatus,
       SUBSTRING(@string, 
           CHARINDEX('=', @string, CHARINDEX(';', @string)) + 1, 
           LEN(@string) - CHARINDEX('=', @string, CHARINDEX(';', @string))) as Youngest
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't know exactly the data field name and the count of data. how to do . Please help me.

Comment: You don't need names, the code above uses just `=` and `;` to get the boundary of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this following code in SP or create a user defined function to achieve your goal

```
declare @commaSeperatedVal varchar(100)
set @commaSeperatedVal='MaritalStatus=M;Youngest=[-0.999,0.999];'
DECLARE @x XML 
SELECT @x = CAST('<A>'+ REPLACE(@commaSeperatedVal,';','</A><A>')+ '</A>' AS XML)

select 'field name ='+ replace(Tval,'=' , ',data is ') from
(
  SELECT t.value('.', 'varchar(100)') as Tval
  FROM @x.nodes('A') AS x(t)
) tbl
where tbl.Tval<>''
```

Comment: Sorry . I mean for When I retrieve the data from table. I will get this data MaritalStatus=M;Youngest=[-0.999,0.999]; Then, I would like to Separate data and field. MaritalStatus will be Field. M will be data. When I excute the SQL, row of key value.like that. Please help me to give simple code.

Comment: Please Clearly mention what output u want?

Comment: I would like to get that like that
I'll get the data example 'MaritalStatus=M;Youngest=[-0.999,1.00];' from other table.
I would like to filed assign that data field .
Set filename = MaritalStatus
set value = M

If I see the ; I would like to do loop again. At that second loop, I would like to assign like that 
set filed name = Youngest
set value = [-0.999,1.00]

Can you help me. give me the sample coding. Thank in Advance.